# Tumblr 'loading more' button

Tags: ajax, tumblr

In the first place I want to say sorry for my bad english . I'm trying to develop a tumblr theme , and add a 'loading more' button . I used JavaScript to determinate the current page and the next one . When 'Loading More' button is pressed , I use jQuery to make a request to next tumblr page ex ( sitename.tumblr.ro/page/next-page )   , get the html , extract the posts html and append it to current page . But the problem is that the like button is not working on the appended posts . When I click the button , noting is happening . The cursor is not even pointing ... Here's my javascript code :

```
 var $holder = $('div.posts_holder');
 var page = null;
 $(document).on('click','div.loading_more.loading_trigger',function(){


 if(page == null)
 {
 page = window.location.href.search('page') > -1 ? window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1] : 1;
 }

 page = Number(page)+1;

 $(this).text('Please Wait..');


 var load_page = '{BlogURL}page/'+page;
 var $saved = $(this);

 //get the page
 $.get(load_page,function(response)
 {


    var $append_html = $(response).find('div.posts_holder');



    if($append_html.html().replace(' ','').trim() == '') 
    {
     $saved.removeClass('loading_trigger');
    }
  $saved.text('Loading More');

  $holder.append($append_html.html()).masonry();
  $holder.masonry( 'reloadItems' );
  $holder.masonry( 'layout' );

  setTimeout(function(){
  $holder.masonry( 'reloadItems' );
  $holder.masonry( 'layout' );

  },800);

    });
```

});

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: No , i'm not . I just found the answer : When a ajax call is made to add new posts you need to tell tumblr that you've added new posts using this line :  Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_page(page); Where 'page' is the number of page you just added.

Comment: @user3817462 To clarify, you want the like buttons to work on new posts that have been you loaded with ajax? Post your answer and I will clean the question up. Thanks and good luck! :D

Comment: Yes , that's right !  I must wait 8 hours :) I will post my answer after that .  Thanks for your support . I hope my answer will help some users .

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer . You must add :Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_page(page); to your javascript after you added new items ,where 'page' is the number of page you just added.